# Nonlinear programming APOPT solver for optimal EV charging not infeasible with variables boundary <= 0 (GEKKO python)

Tags: optimization, gekko

I have tried to do optimal EV charging scheduling using the GEKKO packages. However, my code is stuck on some variable boundary condition when it is set to be lower than or equal to zero, i.e., x=m.Array(m.Var,n_var,value=0,lb=0,ub=1.0). The error message is 'Unsuccessful with error code  0'.
Below is my python script. If you have any advice on this problem, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Thanks,

Chitchai

```py
#------------------------------

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import os
from gekko import GEKKO

print('...... Preparing data for optimal EV charging ........')
#---------- Read data from csv.file -----------)
Main_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
Baseload_path = Main_path + '/baseload_data.csv'
TOU_path = Main_path + '/TOUprices.csv'
EV_path = Main_path + '/EVtravel.csv'
df_Baseload = pd.read_csv(Baseload_path, index_col= 'Time')
df_TOU = pd.read_csv(TOU_path, index_col= 'Time')
df_EVtravel = pd.read_csv(EV_path, index_col= 'EV_no')

#Create and change run directory
rd= r'.\RunDir'
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.abspath(rd)):
    os.mkdir(os.path.abspath(rd))

#--------------------EV charging optimization function----------------#
def OptEV(tou_rate, EV_data, P_baseload):
    """This function is to run EV charging optimization for each houshold"""
 
    #Initialize EV model and traveling data in 96 intervals(interval = 15min)
    s_time= 4*(EV_data[0]//1) + math.ceil(100*(EV_data[0]%1)/15)  #starting time 
    d_time= 4*(EV_data[1]//1) + math.floor(100*(EV_data[1]%1)/15) #departure time
    Pch_rating= EV_data[2]     #charing rated power(kW)
    kWh_bat= EV_data[3]        #Battery rated capacity(kWh)
    int_SoC= EV_data[4]        #Initial battery's SoC(p.u.)
    
    #Calculation charging period
    if d_time<= s_time:
        ch_period = 96+d_time-s_time   
    else:
        ch_period = d_time-s_time
    Np= int(ch_period)
    print('charging period = %d intervals'%(Np))
    
    #Construct revelant data list based on charging period
    ch_time = [0]*Np         #charging time step list
    price_rate = [0]*Np      #electricity price list
    kW_baseload = [0]*Np     #kW house baseload power list 
    
    #Re-arrange charging time, electricity price rate and baseload 
    for i in range(Np):
        t_step = int(s_time)+i
        if t_step <= 95:    #Before midnight
            ch_time[i] = t_step
            price_rate[i] = tou_rate[t_step]
            kW_baseload[i] = P_baseload[t_step]/1000   #active house baseload
        else:      #After midnight
            ch_time[i] = t_step-96
            price_rate[i] = tou_rate[t_step-96]
            kW_baseload[i] = P_baseload[t_step-96]/1000
    
    #Initialize Model
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)         # or m = GEKKO() for solve locally
    m.path = os.path.abspath(rd)    # change run directory

    #define parameter
    ch_eff= m.Const(value=0.90)   #charging/discharging efficiency
    alpha= m.Const(value= 0.00005) #regularization constant battery profile
    net_load= [None]*Np    #net metering houshold load power array
    elec_price= [None]*Np  #purchased electricity price array
    SoC= [None]*(Np+1) #SoC of batteries array  
    
    #initialize variables
    n_var= Np     #number of dicision variables
    x = m.Array(m.Var,n_var,value=0,lb=0,ub=1.0) #dicision charging variables

    #Calculation relevant evaluated parameters
    #x[0] = m.Intermediate(-1.025)
    SoC[0]= m.Intermediate(int_SoC)        #initial battery SoC 
    for i in range(Np):
        #Netload metering evaluation
        net_load[i]= m.Intermediate(kW_baseload[i]+x[i]*Pch_rating)
        
        #electricity cost price evaluation(cent/kWh)
        Neg_pr= (1/4)*net_load[i]*price_rate[i]  # Reverse power cost
        Pos_pr= (1/4)*net_load[i]*price_rate[i]  # Purchased power cost
        elec_price[i]= m.Intermediate(m.if3(net_load[i], Neg_pr, Pos_pr))

        #current battery's SoC evaluation
        j=i+1
        SoC_dch= (1/4)*(x[i]*Pch_rating/ch_eff)/kWh_bat  #Discharging(V2G)
        SoC_ch= (1/4)*ch_eff*x[i]*Pch_rating/kWh_bat     #Discharging
        SoC[j]= m.Intermediate(m.if3(x[i], SoC[j-1]+SoC_dch, SoC[j-1]+SoC_ch))
    #m.solve(disp=False)
   
    #-------Constraint functions--------#
    #EV battery constraint
    m.Equation(SoC[-1] >= 0.80)    #required departure SoC (minimum=80%)
    for i in range(Np):
        j=i+1
        m.Equation(SoC[j] >= 0.20) #lower SoC limit = 20%
    for i in range(Np):
        j=i+1
        m.Equation(SoC[j] <= 0.95) #upper SoC limit = 95%
    
    #household Net-power constraint
    for i in range(Np):
        m.Equation(net_load[i] >= -10.0) #Lower netload power limit
    for i in range(Np):
        m.Equation(net_load[i] <= 10.0) #Upper netload power limit
    
    #Objective functions
    elec_cost = m.Intermediate(m.sum(elec_price))  #electricity cost
    #battery degradation cost
    bat_cost = m.Intermediate(m.sum([alpha*xi**2 for xi in x]))  
    #bat_cost = 0  #Not consider battery degradation cost
    m.Minimize(elec_cost + bat_cost) # objective

    #Set global options
    m.options.IMODE = 3 #steady state optimization

    #Solve simulation
    try:
        m.solve(disp=True)    # solve
        print('--------------Results---------------')
        print('Objective Function= ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
        print('x= ', x)
        print('price_rate= ', price_rate)
        print('net_load= ', net_load)
        print('elec_price= ', elec_price)
        print('SoC= ', SoC)
        print('Charging time= ', ch_time)
    except:
        print('*******Not successful*******')
        print('--------------No convergence---------------')
        # from gekko.apm import get_file
        # print(m._server)
        # print(m._model_name)
        # f = get_file(m._server,m._model_name,'infeasibilities.txt')
        # f = f.decode().replace('\r','')
        # with open('infeasibilities.txt', 'w') as fl:
        #     fl.write(str(f))

    Pcharge = x
    
    return ch_time, Pcharge
    pass   

#---------------------- Run scripts ---------------------#
TOU= df_TOU['Prices']    #electricity TOU prices rate (c/kWh)
Load1= df_Baseload['Load1']
EV_data = [17.15, 8.15, 3.3, 24, 0.50]  #[start,final,kW_rate,kWh_bat,int_SoC]
OptEV(TOU, EV_data, Load1)

#--------------------- End of a script --------------------#
```

Comment: Please post your data files for more specific help. You can see the model with `m.open_folder()` by opening `gk_model0.apm` with a text editor.

Comment: Here is my link for datafiles > https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10OPHeoC6hMPgx4tDfbq4EJa-bQGBkp-l?usp=sharing
 [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10OPHeoC6hMPgx4tDfbq4EJa-bQGBkp-l?usp=sharing) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: John,

After I tried to change the Solver to be IPOPT including increasing the maximum iteration and varying the initial value of control variables, finally, I have got that my code can be found the optimal solution.

Thanks again for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the solver fails to find a solution and reports "Solution Not Found", there is a [troubleshooting method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942615/how-to-fix-solution-not-found-error-in-python-gekko-optimal-control-code) to diagnose the problem. The first thing to do is to look at the solver output with `m.solve(disp=True)`. The solver may have identified either an infeasible problem or it reached the maximum number of iterations without converging to a solution. In your case, it identified the problem as infeasible.

**Infeasible Problem**

If the solver failed because of infeasible equations then it found that the combination of variables and equations is not solvable. You can try to relax the variable bounds or identify which equation is infeasible with the `infeasibilities.txt` file in the run directory. Retrieve the `infeasibilities.txt` file from the local run directory that you can view with `m.open_folder()` when `m=GEKKO(remote=False)`.

**Maximum Iteration Limit**

If the solver reached the default iteration limit (`m.options.MAX_ITER=250`) then you can either try to increase this limit or else try the strategies below.

- Try a different solver by setting `m.options.SOLVER=1` for APOPT, `m.options.SOLVER=2` for BPOPT, `m.options.SOLVER=3` for IPOPT, or `m.options.SOLVER=0` to try all the available solvers.
- Find a feasible solution first by solving a square problem where the number of variables is equal to the number of equations. Gekko a couple options to help with this including `m.options.COLDSTART=1` (sets STATUS=0 for all FVs and MVs) or `m.options.COLDSTART=2` (sets STATUS=0 and performs block diagonal triangular decomposition to find possible infeasible equations).
- Once a feasible solution is found, try optimizing with this solution as the initial guess.

Comment: Hi Prof.John,


Many thanks for your reply. I will try to find out and fix it as per your suggestion. In addition, the below link is data files relating to my code.


https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10OPHeoC6hMPgx4tDfbq4EJa-bQGBkp-l?usp=sharing
 [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10OPHeoC6hMPgx4tDfbq4EJa-bQGBkp-l?usp=sharing) _italic_ **bold**


Chitchai